# Using the appearance of a file as a trigger

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to figure out a way to interface between an arduino-controlled system, and a software that will automatically create files in a certain filepath over time.

I don't need arduino to read the file, or extract anything from the file, only become aware of the file coming into existence (from the other software) and trigger the already programmed sequences.

If anyone has any ideas on how I can accomplish this (or if you need any clarification), please let me know.

Comment: What Operating System is this running under?

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I am asuming you're not the one who wrote the software that creates files. In that case, take a look at [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28VS.85%29.aspx). Whenever you retrieve the change in the directory, just send a serial message to the arduino and trigger the sequence.